# Contracting an expanded DatePicker on SwiftUI / MacOS

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way to get a `DatePicker` that has been expanded to contract when the user clicks on a date?

The following code will crash the app - or at least put it into the locked state.

There is a `Text` component showing the date. When you click on it the `DatePicker` appears in its place - but there is no way to dismiss it after it is an expanded mode. Trying to swap back to the original `Text`, by setting edit mode to false when the date changes effectively locks the app:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var date: Date = .now
    @State private var editMode: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if editMode {
                DatePicker("Test", selection: $date)
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .onChange(of: date) { _ in
                        editMode = false
                    }
                    .frame(width: 50)
            } else {
                Text(date.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        editMode = true
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Ideally I'd also be able to dismiss it programatically.

I have tried using a `ZStack` with opacity control, such as:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var date: Date = .now
    @State private var editMode: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
                DatePicker("Test", selection: $date)
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .onChange(of: date) { _ in
                        editMode = false
                    }
                    .frame(width: 50)
                    .opacity(editMode ? 1.0 : 0.0)
                Text(date.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        editMode = true
                    }
                    .opacity(editMode ? 0.0 : 1.0)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

But this isn't working in my actual use case. I'd really like to know if there was a way of dismissing that `DatePicker` expanded form.